# Has Weyl justified the terminology "Classical" to matrix groups?

Tags: soft-question

In the theory of finite groups, the research is devoted to specific families of groups such as "nilpotent groups, solvable groups, matrix groups (or classical groups)", etc.

Among these families, the groups of matrices like $GL_n$, $SL_n$, $U_n$, $O_n$, $Sp_n$ etc are often termed as classical groups.

As per my visit to these groups, I saw, in many contexts, that these are the most interesting groups, which are not only studied in different branches of mathematics, but also in Physics. Then, the name of these groups, *classical*, gives me a realization that they look certainly *classical*.

Who termed these groups as "classical"? Probably, it was Hermann Weyl. Supposing that this is true, has Weyl justified this naming to these groups, when he came to see the beauty of these groups?

Comment: They are classical in opposition to the remaining ones, which are exceptional; the latter where only found when Cartan tried to list Lie groups exhaustively. The name is essentially self-descriptive, really. I doubt he or anyone thought it necessary to explain the choice of the term...